# SWIFT- IOS : modify a value using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a struct that contains only one element

In my code i save this element as "123"

At this moment i would like to modify the element to "1000"

However my element never change

```
struct Key {
     static let Keyone = ""
}
```

equal to "123"

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
         defaults.setValue("123", forKey: Key.Keyone)
         defaults.synchronize()
```

when i printed it using

```
defaults.stringForKey(Key.Keyone)
```

everything is well and the output is 123

Now, trying to do the same to change the Keyone, but it doesn't work

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
         defaults.setValue("1000", forKey: Key.Keyone)
         defaults.synchronize()
defaults.stringForKey(Key.Keyone)
```

the output is still 123

so what could be the best solution for this issue

Comment: Use .set instead of setValue
and Object instead of stringForKey

follow this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults) for more information

Comment: @mustafa96m as we may assume, Anthony's code is in Swift 2, so your advice won't help here.

Comment: Your `Keyone` is empty, set some string key with it

Comment: @NiravD that's worked!. but why ?

Comment: You need to specify the key name.

Comment: @NiravD Thank you for your help
i would like to note  also that: by using 4 elements in the strcut without setting any string key, i was facing another problem:
all the elements save the same value without any logical reason.. so by setting a string key for eachone, i avoided this problem too, so thank you

Comment: @AnthonyShahine Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically keys in NSUserDefaults are used to uniquely identify the stored data. And you are trying to save your data with and empty String. You need to do something like this.

```
struct Key {
 static let Keyone = "someKey"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like this ;

```
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(1000, forKey: Key.Keyone)
        defaults.synchronize()
        defaults.integerForKey(Key.Keyone)
```

Not "1000" use 1000 for `int` values and use `setInteger` for integers

Example usages;

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
//Set
defaults.setInteger(yourInt, forKey: "intKey")
//Get
defaults.integerForKey("intKey")
```

Comment: This is not a solution

Comment: @Vyacheslav for integers need to setInteger. I explain thats